# Existence of compatible almost complex structure of symplectic fibration with nice property

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $\pi: E \to B$ be a  fibration over a closed surface $B$ with fier $g(F) \ge 2$. Suppose that both of $B$ and $F$ are closed surfaces and  $g(B) \ge2$ and $g(F) \ge 2$.   Fix a  Kahler structure $(vol_B, j)$ on  $B$.    Given  a fiberwise non-degenerate    two form  $\omega$ on $E$, then we define a sympletic form $\Omega=\omega + K\pi^*vol_B$ on $E$ for sufficiently large $K$.  Define $\mathcal{J}_{\tau}(E, \pi, \Omega)$   as the space of $\Omega$-tame almost complex structures on $E$ such that $\pi_* \circ J=j \circ \pi_* $.

Given $J \in \mathcal{J}_{\tau}(E, \pi, \Omega)$, any embedded holomorphic curve $C$ that is not contained in a fiber must intersect every fiber positively, then we get a branched cover $\pi \vert_C : C \to B$. According to Riemann Hurwitz formula, we know that  $g(C) \ge 2$.

Define $\mathcal{J}_{comp}(E, \pi, \Omega)$   as the space of $\Omega$-compatible almost complex structures.  Let $\mathcal{U}_L  \subset \mathcal{J}_{comp}(E, \pi, \Omega)$ be collection of almost complex structures with the following property:

> Given $J \in \mathcal{U}_L$, all embedded $J$ holomorphic curve $C$ with $\int_C \Omega< L$ has genus at least two.

Obviously, $\mathcal{J}_{comp}(E, \pi, \Omega) \cap \mathcal{J}_{\tau}(E, \pi, \Omega) \subset \mathcal{U}_L $  for any $L$.  Moreover, $\mathcal{U}_L$  is open by Gromov compactness argument. In particular,   $\mathcal{U}_L$  contain a open neighborhood of $\mathcal{J}_{comp}(E, \pi, \Omega) \cap \mathcal{J}_{\tau}(E, \pi, \Omega)$. However, $\mathcal{U}_L$ may shrink to  $\mathcal{J}_{comp}(E, \pi, \Omega) \cap \mathcal{J}_{\tau}(E, \pi, \Omega)$ as $L \to \infty$. 
For my purpose, I need to consider the set $ \mathcal{U}= \cap_L\mathcal{U}_L$ and I hope that the transversality of all embedded $J$ holomorphic curves hold for generic $J \in  \mathcal{U}$.

> My question: It is possible to show that  $ \mathcal{U}$ is a "larger" set containing $\mathcal{J}_{comp}(E, \pi, \Omega) \cap \mathcal{J}_{\tau}(E, \pi, \Omega) $ in some sense?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but other than having the word set in the question, how is this a set theory question?

Comment: You are right, I posted a wrong label...